# CSS sometimes does not load properly on initial load

Tags: css, rendering, refresh, html-rendering

Sometimes the header of my website does not form properly when I first load a page.

Incorrect:

In the screenshot below the headings are inside the black horizontal line

[alt text http://techboy.co.uk/misc/Incorrect_View.PNG](http://techboy.co.uk/misc/Incorrect_View.PNG)

After refreshing the page, there is space below the headings:

[alt text http://techboy.co.uk/misc/Correct_View.PNG](http://techboy.co.uk/misc/Correct_View.PNG)

This issue has been seen on several pages, not just the one I have taken a screenshot of (http://www.getmecooking.com/blog/review-of-food-bloggers-connect-london-november-2009)

Please can you tell me why this might be occurring and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't recreate this bug in Firefox 3.6, is it happening in a specific browser?

Comment: No, I have seen it in FireFox 3.6 and IE8. The issue is intermittent so hard to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We identified a DB issue that was intermittently causing the dynamic content of pages to load a little slower than normal. Fixing that seems to have fixed the CSS issue!

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you CSS file is loading. the problem seems to be a {position: } issue. i've faced the similar problem with elements that are absolute positioned but are not contained in another div which is relative positioned

Comment: Good thought, but the only absolute position I have on the page is for the AddThis menu, which is below the header div. So I don't think that is an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the `@import`s does it still happen? Just include the stylesheets in the page directly and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I can try that, the problem is that the issue is intermittent so I am not able to test it reliably. If it turns our that doing this resolves the issue, what would the proper fix be? Thanks.

Comment: If it fixes the problem (which btw I was able to reproduce in Firefox 3.6 on Linux) then the proper fix is to leave it fixed :)

Comment: I wouldn't be keen on having all of the CSS within the page though :-) I have read http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/ which says that 'link' gets multiple CSS files in parallel and '@import' gets them sequentially, so link is faster. Plus the 4th comment there says that switching to link resolved an issue which sounds similar to the issue I am experiencing, so I will try that first :-)

Comment: What I'm suggesting is using `link` instead of `link` with `@import`s. So yea, I think we're on the same page here.

Comment: I have moved to link, but I still intermittently see the issue :-(